# How to run parseString() function synchronously in Javascript node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code, where I run `parseString()`to extract some information from an xml file

```
function parseTime(){

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var data = fs.readFileSync('C:\\Temp\\tasks\\acis\\110-1100.sat\\110-1100.sat.response.xml', {encoding:'utf8'});

parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {

var timeString = result.Message.Response[0].Events[0].MessageReportEvent[8].$.Message;
var fileTime = timeString.substr(13,20);
var filetimeVal = parseFloat(fileTime);

console.log(filetimeVal);

return filetimeVal;

});

};
```

What changes should I do to run `parseString` synchronously or is there a way to extract the xml data via a deifferent synchronous method

Comment: Did you look at the API documentation of this library? Do they provide a synchronous method? If yes, use that, if not, you are out of luck. Change your code to work asynchronously.

Comment: the **_documentation_** implies that the callback is called synchronously, there's an option to make it async - https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js#options

Answer (score 1):

The callback of the `parseString` already runs synchronously. Your program would reach the parsed results before it reaches any other line of code.

There is `async` switch which is `false` by default in the options.

However the developers warn that this default might change in the future.

> async (default false): Should the callbacks be async? This might be an
>   incompatible change if your code depends on sync execution of
>   callbacks. Future versions of xml2js might change this default, so the
>   recommendation is to not depend on sync execution anyway. Added in
>   0.2.6.